# Optimize a function with $30,000$ variables. Possible? Reasonable?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a nonlinear optimisation problem of the form:

$$ \min \:~ (a - \rho_{a})^2 + (b - \rho_{b})^2 + (c - \rho_{c})^2 $$

where $a,b,c$ are constants, and $\rho$ are different functions of around $30,000$ variables, say $x_{i}$. The nominator fo these functions includes a weighted sum of most of them, plus a weighted sum of their pairwise combinations, including squares. The denominator includes a type of "norm", this is the squared root of the squared sum of each of them. The key difference between the three $\rho$ functions is the subset of variables included. But there is huge overlap.

I also have lower and upper bounds for each of these variables.

**Is there any hope I can achieve a meaningful optimisation?** If so, would you recommend a particular language/optimisation tool? I'm open to anything really.

Comment: Instead of describing in English what the $\rho$ functions look like, $\LaTeX$ them. Parsing natural language is painful.

Comment: I think it does not make much difference what the function actually is (beyond that is is non-linear, with variables on the nominator and denominator). But if more people suggest that, I will.

Comment: It sounds like you have large co-variance matrix.  Which means that is should be pretty easy to calculate your objective function.  If you wanted to be analytical with it, you would find the principle components.  Likely a very small subset of your variables drive the changes to the objective function.  The other approach would be to perturb the variables, find the sensitivity of your objective to each variable.  Optimize the variable with the greatest sensitivity, then step to the next most significant.

Comment: @DougM The formulas actually are the correlation between three vectors of around 80,000 observations where in total around 30,000 are missing. I think that most of the variables are of importance, and there are not many "outliers" that could drive the relationship. PCA might not work. I cannot find a reasonable introduction to perturbation methods, or implementations in e.g. Matlab. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the analytical form of the functions. This might help in writing  an analytical upper bound or lower bound to the objective function that will help in improving the convergence time of the optimization algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

For that number of variables, the trick is to be careful and not choose an algorithm that requires the computation of a dense Hessian.  There may be a better way to cache things, but a matrix-free inexact Newton method should work.  Basically, it's Newton's method where the optimality system is solved inexactly using some kind of Krylov method like conjugate-gradient.  Both trust-region and line-search variants exist, which should guarantee convergence.  As far as the performance, it will depend greatly on how the eigenvalues of the Hessian are distributed.  If they're well clustered, then it should work well.  If they're not, it'll perform poorly.  Figuring this out can be, well, a pain because for that many variables it's unlikely that you could compute the dense Hessian and just check.  Really, the best option is to just code the derivatives and try the algorithms to see if they work.

As far as software, [Optizelle](http://www.optimojoe.com/products/optizelle/) implements the requisite algorithms and has interfaces to C++, Python, and MATLAB.  It's also BSD licensed.  Use the development version as it works much better.  One of these days, I'll post some installers, which'll make installation easier.  If you ask on the support forum, I'll do it sooner rather than later.

In any case, 30000 variables by itself isn't a problem.  I've scaled certain problems out to half a billion variables, but they had a relatively compact spectra and I had a lot of computation to calculate the requisite derivatives.